# Symfony add flash message in LogoutSuccessHandler not work

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have set a logout success handler in security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
             logout:
                 invalidate_session: true
                 success_handler: acme.security.logout_success_handler
```

I have set the service in services.yml:

```
acme.security.logout_success_handler:
        class: ACME\FooBundle\Security\Handler\LogoutSuccessHandler
```

and implement the code in LogoutSuccessHandler .php

```
class LogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onLogoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'you have been logged out successfully');

        return new RedirectResponse('/');
    }
}
```

Now, if i have any flash message, i print from twig:

```
{% for flashType, flashMessages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
   {% for flashMessage in flashMessages %}
   <div class="flash-message-{{ flashType }}">{{ flashMessage|raw }}</div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but no message are printed. I think the session is regenerated after logout success handler are called and flash message are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `invalidate_session: false` instead of `invalidate_session: true` so the session won't be invalidated. See [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#invalidate-session).